# Event on a selected ComboBoxItem

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, radio-button

I have a `ComboBox` control. When a particular item is selected, I would like to disable some `RadioButton` controls.

Is there any particular event that I could use to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `SelectionChanged` event.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    radioButton1.IsEnabled = comboBox1.SelectedItem == x;

    // or

    radioButton1.IsEnabled = comboBox1.SelectedValue == x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
 private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, 
        System.EventArgs e)
{
     if(((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem.ToString() == "your value")
              radioBtn1.IsEnabled = false;
}
```

Comment: Erf doesn't works :

Warning 1 Possible unintended reference comparison; to get a value comparison, cast the left hand side to type 'string